# Scrapy doesn't scrape data from a particular field in the same page which I have successfully scraped other data from

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I am actually very new to Scrapy and I'm not sure why am I not getting the information which I want. I am using Scrapy on the website www.kayak.com and i want to extract the check in and check out time from all the hotels in New York. I have successfully scraped out data from the same page which the check in and check out time is in but couldnt scrape out data for both these fields.

The code I have is shown below:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from hotel_crawl.items import HotelCrawlItem
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import urlparse

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
name = "kayaksite"
allowed_domains = ["www.kayak.com"]
start_urls = ["http://www.kayak.com/New-York-Hotels.15830.hotel.ksp"]

rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(
    restrict_xpaths=("//a[@class='actionlink pagenumber' [contains(text(),'Next')]", )), callback="parse_item", follow=True),

def parse_start_url(self, response):
    print "test"
    self.logger.info('Hi, this is an item page! %s', response.url)
    item = HotelCrawlItem()

    name = response.xpath("//a[@class='hotelname hotelresultsname']//text()").extract()
    price = [BeautifulSoup(i).get_text() for i in response.xpath("//div[@class='pricerange']").extract()]
review = response.xpath("//a[@class='reviewsoverview']/strong/text()").extract()

    url = response.xpath("//a[@class='hotelname hotelresultsname']//@href").extract()

    alldata = zip(name, price, review, url)

    for i in alldata:
        item['name'] = i[0]
        item['price'] = i[1]
        item['review'] = i[2]
        request = scrapy.Request(urlparse.urljoin(response.url, i[3]), callback=self.parse_item2)

        request.meta['item'] = item
        yield request


def parse_item(self, response):
    self.logger.info('Hi, this is an item page! %s', response.url)
    item = HotelCrawlItem()
    name = response.xpath("//a[@class='hotelname hotelresultsname']//text()").extract()
    price = [BeautifulSoup(i).get_text() for i in response.xpath("//div[@class='pricerange']").extract()]
    review = response.xpath("//a[@class='reviewsoverview']/strong/text()").extract()
    url = response.xpath("//a[@class='hotelname hotelresultsname']//@href").extract()

    alldata = zip(name, price, review, url)

    for i in alldata:
        item['name'] = i[0]
        item['price'] = i[1]
        item['review'] = i[2]
        request = scrapy.Request(urlparse.urljoin(response.url, i[3]), callback=self.parse_item2)
        request.meta['item'] = item
        yield request

def parse_item2(self, response):
    print "test--------------"
    self.logger.info('Hi, this is an item page! %s', response.url)
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['location'] = response.xpath("//*[@id='detailsOverviewContactInfo']/div/span/span[1]/text()").extract()
    item['postcode'] = response.xpath("//*[@id='detailsOverviewContactInfo']/div/span/span[3]/text()").extract()   
    item['check_in'] = response.xpath("//*[@id='goodToKnow']/div/div[2]/div[2]/text()").extract()
    item['check_out'] = response.xpath("//*[@id='goodToKnow']/div/div[2]/div[2]/text()").extract()
    yield item
```

Comment: Your check-in,check-out x-paths are not returning any values.For other attributes like location and postcode ,your x-paths are working fine.In addition to that they are two check-in and check-out data points  in that page[http://www.kayak.com/New-York-Hotels-Metro-Apartments.341670.ksp]. Please try the following xpath for chek-in[//input[@name='checkin_date']/@value] below get rates.

Comment: Oh im trying to get the check-in and check-out times from the "Good to know" section as u see below the "Amenities" section. Not the input fields.